# react-slick slider Custom arrows

Tags: javascript, slick.js, react-slick

I am using `react-slick` library for slider component, my `Slider` component contains 8 slides , initially , my previous and next buttons are working fine , `i want the next button should be disabled when there no slides are left to move` , previous button is working fine , but next button is not working  properly .

Here in the above image you can see the next button is still enabled and i am able to click even there are no slides to move , i want this next arrow to be disabled, when there are no slides.

this is my code

```
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    nextArrow: <NextButton />,
    prevArrow: <PrevButton />,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          initialSlide: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
        },
      },
    ],
  }

  function NextButton(props) {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props
    return (
      <div
        id="next"
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style }}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <button type="button" className="card-SlideTrigger">
          <SlideNextIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }

  function PrevButton(props) {
    const { className, style, onClick } = props
    return (
      <div
        id="prev"
        className={className}
        style={{ ...style }}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <button type="button" className="card-SlideTrigger">
          <SlidePrevIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

, i want this next arrow to be disabled, when there are no slides.